# wordpress shortcode to json

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

If someone has an experience in creating a regex handler on JavaScript, a help will be much appreciated. I'm stuck at converting Wordpress shortcodes structure like

```
[container atr1='123' atr2='123']

  [column width="30"]
    [textblock]
        <p>fdsfsdf</p>
    [/textblock]
  [/column]

[/container]
```

to JSON like

```
{
'type': 'container'
'content' : [
   {
    'type' : 'column'
    'content' : [
       {
          'type': 'textblock'
          'content': '<p>fdsfsdf</p>'
       }
    ],
    'width': '30'
   }
   ],
'atr1': '123',
'atr2': '123'
}
```

Please give a help or tutorial for creating handler. I've found one http://ejohn.org/files/htmlparser.js, but it looks very complicated and unclear for my understanding.
Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Hey Vladimir! What's the context for this? Are you hoping to have the shortcode render as JSON? Should it be assigned as a variable in a `<script>` tag?

Comment: Hi @CameronHurd ! I want to create a visual builder for wordpress. If the page of wordpress already have some shortcode structure it needs to convert it to html like for visual editing. I see it like `Shortcode<->JSON<->HTML`, other visual editors work in structure like `Shortcode<->HTML`. Don't understand clearly, what you mean, about variable, but in `<script>` tag – yes, it's javascript. No other places of execution javascript code browser not allows :)

Comment: When you say 'create a visual builder' are you meaning, for instance a tool or button that extends the TinyMCE toolbar on wp's visual editor?

Comment: I'm afraid the question might be unnecessary, then! Because you could just have the 'visual builder' insert the shortcode into the editor's content. The HTML would be automatically parsed and shortcodes would display on output!

Comment: @CameronHurd if you have already content with shortcodes on the page in wordpress, you will needed to create a structure of HTML to work with in visual editor. I need content of wordpress (plain), that already was on the page with shortcodes to be converted in JSON like structure.

Comment: Oh! So you'd like the shortcodes to be parsed *in* the visual editor?

Comment: @CameronHurd friend, for now, i only need the shortcodes structure (wordpress plain content) to be converted to JSON objects, nothing else.

Comment: @VladimirLukyanov - Did you find a solution to this ? I'm attempting something similar and if you did find a solution, it would make a great starting point. Thanks.

Comment: @Norman Hi Norman, for now, still no solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

As of wordpress version 4.9.8 there is a built-in JavaScript function (in //wp-includes/js/shortcode.js):

```
wp.shortcode.next( shortcode_tag, text_to_parse, index_where_start_search )
```

Not very comfortable but it interprets shortcodes with and without closing tag and attributes..

**It returns:**

- **index**: The index where the match occurred so you can easily match the
  next shortcode using the matched index plus 1.
- **content**: The content actually matched, shortcode tags and all.
- **shortcode**: The wp.shortcode object created from the matched shortcode
  string.